# How can i ensure that only one call is made simultaneous with angular interceptor?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-http-interceptors, rxjs6

The angular interceptor looks like this:

```
public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

  catchError(err => {
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          if (err.status === 401) {

              this.auth.getToken().subscribe((refreshOk: boolean) => {
                if (!refreshOk) {
                  this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
                }
              });
          }
      }

      return Observable.throw(err);
  })
);
```

The issue is that four different api call are made at once. So four getToken calls are made simultaneous. Only one call would be enough. How can i ensure that only one call is made at once?

Answer (score 0):

In that place where you do your api calls, you can use the `race` observable and put your api call inside them. The first that responds wins and and the others are rejected.

```
// RxJS v6+
race(
  api.get('http://abc/foo'),
  api.get('http://abc/bar'),
  api.get('http://abc/baz'),
);

// RxJS v5
Observable.race(
  api.get('http://abc/foo'),
  api.get('http://abc/bar'),
  api.get('http://abc/baz'),
);
```